# Segue to next view after authenticating with Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, fbsdk

When the view controller with my Facebook login button loads in, it checks for the access token to see if the user is already logged in:

```
if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil)
    {
        //user not logged in
        print("User is not logged in")
    } else {
        print("User is logged in")
}
```

This is working correctly as when I open my app it says "User is logged in"
so I added a segue under the print statement:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueID", sender: nil)
```

It still prints that it is logged in, but does not perform the segue. The segue ID is correct. I have even tried getting the storyboard and getting the view controller by ID and then presenting it, but that did not work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueID", sender: self)
```

Comment: Thanks John, trying it now.

Comment: Hmmmm. That still didn't work for me. I login with Facebook, then back out to my first view controller and back into the sign up view controller and console prints "User is logged in" but the segue doesn't happen still.

Comment: Okay now try to use super instead of self. If it will not work just override performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: `super.performSegueWithIdentifier("signUpToMap", sender: self)` did not work and neither did `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signUpToMap", sender: superclass)`    it made me use superclass, super expected '.' or '[' after.   Going to look up the best way of overriding now.

Comment: I tried `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`                `let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mapView") as! ViewController`
 `self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` and also tried `self.showViewController` and neither opened the view I have called "mapView" that is of class ViewController :/

Comment: if you can post the snippet on gist

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c89c0c67f7cabb35d858      and as soon as this view gets loaded, since I've already logged into Facebook, it prints "User is logged in" so it gets to the correct part of the if.

Comment: Update: I overlooked this error in the console because the FBSDK was printing so much: 
`2015-10-19 12:57:38.625 appName[648:138506] Warning: Attempt to present <appName.ViewController: 0x14557f950> on <appName.signUpView: 0x1455792a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: I fixed it by moving my code to the ViewDidAppear method instead of will appear. Thanks so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to present the view from within the viewWillAppear method. This was fixed by moving it to the viewDidAppear method.